# How to store data with a dynamic key, and an array of data?

Tags: swift

So I'm working on an IRC client for iOS but I can't figure out how to store some of the data. Previously I've mostly been a web dev, so in php I can just make an array like $channels[$dynamic_channel_name][$array_of_users].

I can't seem to find any way of doing this in swift. So what I'm trying to do is have an array of channels with a sub array of users for each channel.

I"m guessing this isn't how things are done for swift? The dynamic channel name is whats making everything I find on google useless, so hopefully someone here can drop a knowledge bomb.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally when asking questions you should explain what you have tried, what your assumptions and expectations are, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP apparently lets you use a string as an index for an "array". In Swift this is a different data structure called a dictionary. You can create a dictionary like this:

```
let channels = [String: [User]]
```

This creates a variable named `channels` which contains a dictionary which maps a key which is a `String` to an array of `User`s (you might not have created this type, so it might just be an array of `String`s for example.

You can then access similarly to before:

```
let users = channels[dynamic_channel_name]
```

The variable `users` now contains a list of your users.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Makes sense for accessing the data, but I feel like a complete idiot that I don't know how to write to the dictionary like that lol

Comment: Here's a good place to start with the differences between arrays and dictionaries: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html